# How to remove a particular value from an array in Node.js

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I have an array  of values

```
var test =[];
test [1] = [
    {"myself":true,chat_user:11,"message":"Hi"},
    {"myself":true,chat_user:11,"message":"Evida"},
    {"myself":false,chat_user:11,"message":"yes"},
]

test [6] = [
    {"myself":true,chat_user:13,"message":"Hi"},
    {"myself":true,chat_user:13,"message":"Evida"},
    {"myself":false,chat_user:13,"message":"yes"},
]

test [9] = [
    {"myself":true,chat_user:22,"message":"Hi"},
    {"myself":true,chat_user:22,"message":"Evida"},
    {"myself":false,chat_user:22,"message":"yes"},
]
```

Now i have to remove  the entry test[6] and need to get the remaining array

ie

```
 test [1] = [
        {"myself":true,chat_user:11,"message":"Hi"},
        {"myself":true,chat_user:11,"message":"Evida"},
        {"myself":false,chat_user:11,"message":"yes"},
    ]

    test [9] = [
        {"myself":true,chat_user:22,"message":"Hi"},
        {"myself":true,chat_user:22,"message":"Evida"},
        {"myself":false,chat_user:22,"message":"yes"},
    ]
```

Is there any function  in node js, for getting this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use:

`delete test[6]`

Comment: is there any way to find  an element is present  or not in the given  array ?

Comment: @LintoPD What do you exactly mean, can you please explain?